# Error in upload_file(x) : is.character(path) is not TRUE in loop

Tags: r, azure, image-processing, face-api

I am using Microsoft Face API to detect face emotions. After trial and error, I have the following code that works for a single file:

```
local <- "/mypath/image.jpg"

x_recognition <- function (x) {

  y = POST(Oxford,
           body = upload_file(x),
           add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/octet-stream",
                                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"=csAPI))
           )

      do.call(rbind,content(y)[[1]]$faceAttributes['emotion'])

}

x_recognition(local)

        anger contempt disgust fear happiness neutral sadness surprise
emotion 0     0        0       0    0         1       0       0
```

But my goal is to process multiple images contained inside a folder. So, I have written the following code but without success:

```
Image_list <- list.files(path = "/mypath", pattern="*.jpg", full.names=TRUE)
append_list <- data.frame()

for (x in 1:length(Image_list)) {

  y = POST(Oxford,
           body = upload_file(x),
           add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/octet-stream",
                                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"=csAPI))
  )

  emotionID = do.call(rbind, content(y)[[1]]$faceAttributes['emotion'])

  append_list <- rbind(append_list, emotionID)

}
```

The above code gives following error:

```
Error in upload_file(x) : is.character(path) is not TRUE
```

I have spent the past hour or so trying to figure out the solution. `list.files` does not seem to be the problem.

```
> Image_List[1]
[1] "/mypath/image1.jpg"

>  Image_List
[1] "/mypath/image1.jpg"
[2] "/mypath/image2.jpg"
[3] "/mypath/image3.jpg"
```

When I try running one selected image, it works:

```
x_recognition(Image_List[1])
        anger contempt disgust fear happiness neutral sadness surprise
emotion 0     0        0       0    0         1       0       0
```

The `Error in upload_file(x) : is.character(path) is not TRUE` appears only when I try to loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your loop, `x` is a number ranging from 1 to `length(image_list)`. You probably want `image_list[x]`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. How could I have missed that ; p... If you post that as an answer, I will select it. I think it could be helpful for those who encounter a similar issue in the future.

Comment: @HongOoi Would you post the comment as an answer so [Jim O] can mark this comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, `x` is a number ranging from 1 to `length(image_list)`. You probably want `image_list[x]`.